# How to close activity with alert dialog when back press?

Tags: android

I'm opening alert dialog activity. Everything is fine, only problem is when user press back in AndroidCommand activity - alertdialog open perfectly, but when again press back button - just dialog close, not dialog activity. So it require two times back press to back to AndroidCommand activity. How I will close dialog with activity when cancel dialog?

```
public class AndroidCommand extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode()) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(AndroidCommand.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final String items[] = {"Movie","Music","Book"};
        AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ab.setTitle("Dialog Title");
        ab.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int choice) {
                if(choice == 0) {

                }
                else if(choice == 1) {

                }
                else if(choice == 2) {

                }
            }
        });
        ab.show();
    }
```

Comment: finish(); // Call once

Answer (score 0):

call

```
finish()
```

method on Back pressed

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK == event.getKeyCode()) {

    finish();
    return true;

 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just override ,

```
      @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//  super.onBackPressed();


 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Dictation Alert")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.galleryalart)
            .setMessage("Do You want save dictation??")
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int          which)    {

      //do other stuff here      
        finish()
    }
      })
 .setPositiveButton("yes", new OnClickListener() {

  //do other stuff here      
  finish()
   }).show
   }
```